# Can't use ResourceType - Reference installed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reference

I am trying to use:

```
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute.ResourceType
```

And my visual studio does not recognize it.
I have the reference installed:
 [image: References]

And in the model I cannot use it:
[image: Model]

I have no idea why this is happening. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your code, not an image of it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a closing `)` after the `Name` property. Your attribute needs to be

```
[Display(Name = "Name", ResourceType = typeof(...))]
public int Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks so much of your help. Next time I'll post the code, I thought it was helpful to see the image. 
Anyway, I was really blind. I think I must rest for today :)